# drf-yasg : How can we use doc-string of different methods other than standard http method for swagger api documentation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I am using drf-yasg and django-rest-framework.
I am having one common parent class which is having all http method defined, which will be inherited in sub-classes where business logic methods will be overided. I want subclass overrided method docstring in swagger api documentation

```
class BaseAPIView(APIView):
    """
    Base API View.
    """
    def get(self, request):
        """
        Base API get method description.
        """
        result = self.process_get()  # Call the overridden method
        return Response(result)

    def process_get(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
        

class DerivedAPIView(BaseAPIView):
    """
    Derived API View.
    """
   
    def process_get(self):
        """
        List all items.
        """
        items = [
            {"name": "Item 1", "description": "Description of Item 1", "price": 10.99},
            {"name": "Item 2", "description": "Description of Item 2", "price": 20.99}
        ]
        return Response(items)
```

Here in swagger document for DerivedAPIView get method i want DerivedAPIView process_get method docstring as api documentation.